# custom UIAlertView called by javascript of a UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, uialertview

i have a custom alertvew, when a button is pressed inside the uiwebview calls javascript:

function doSomething(event) {
                alert("simple test");
                return false;
            }
i'd like that "alert" open my custom uialert.
is it possible?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

found that code that works for me:

```
@interface UIWebView (JavaScriptAlert) 

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;

@end

@implementation UIWebView (JavaScriptAlert)

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    UIAlertView* dialogue = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MdC_Base_PopUp.png"];
    theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:16 topCapHeight:16];
    CGSize theSize = [dialogue frame].size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);
    [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, dialogue.frame.size.width, dialogue.frame.size.height)];
    theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    dialogue.layer.contents = (id)[theImage CGImage];

    [dialogue show];
    [dialogue autorelease];
}

@end
```